# Loading data from a sqlite database in Java?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am new to the world of Java and sqlite database. I was trying out some codes about loading data from a database into a tabular view using java in eclipse. Now, here is the thing, when my data loads from the database, i want to add an extra column which contains a checkbox(unchecked). Can someone suggest me how do i implement it? Please note that when i run the code, it works absolutely fine and shows no error....I am able to see all the records in my table without any error. Just want an unchecked checkbox to be added to each row so that when i click on it, i can do something. Thats my goal..

Here is what i tried so far.. I have two classes namely:-
1. sqliteConnection.java(which is for connection )
2. employeeinfo.java class which is for loading the data from the database into a table and other functionalities.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class sqliteConnection {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection dbConnector()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Documents\\MyJavaProjects\\Phone\\Employee.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Succesful");

            return conn;

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public sqliteConnection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

employeeinfo.java --

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class employeeinfo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    employeeinfo frame = new employeeinfo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    Connection connection = null;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;

    public employeeinfo() {
        connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 842, 457);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblJframe = new JLabel("Jframe2");
        lblJframe.setBounds(47, 37, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblJframe);

        JButton btnLoad = new JButton("Load");
        btnLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            PreparedStatement pat;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query = "select eid,Name,Surname,Age from EmployeeInfo ";
                    pat = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                    ResultSet rs = pat.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));





                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        });
        btnLoad.setBounds(104, 33, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLoad);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(429, 48, 370, 232);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("EID");
        lblName.setBounds(10, 98, 46, 21);
        contentPane.add(lblName);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(107, 99, 126, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblName_1 = new JLabel("Name");
        lblName_1.setBounds(10, 154, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblName_1);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(107, 151, 126, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);

        JLabel lblSurname = new JLabel("Surname");
        lblSurname.setBounds(10, 204, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSurname);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(104, 201, 126, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);

        JLabel lblAge = new JLabel("Age");
        lblAge.setBounds(10, 278, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAge);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBounds(104, 275, 126, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_3);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                PreparedStatement pat;
                try {
                    String query = "insert into EmployeeInfo(EID,name,surname,age) values(?,?,?,?)";
                    pat = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                     pat.setString(1, textField.getText());
                      pat.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
                      pat.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
                        pat.setString(4, textField_3.getText());
                        pat.execute();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved successfully");


                    pat.close();




                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
        btnSave.setBounds(72, 349, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSave);

        JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText("");
                textField_1.setText("");
                textField_2.setText("");
                textField_3.setText("");



            }
        });
        btnClear.setBounds(206, 349, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClear);

        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try
                {

                    String query="Update EmployeeInfo set EID='"+textField.getText()+"',Name='"+textField_1.getText()+"'"
                            +",Surname='"+textField_2.getText()+"',Age='"+textField_3.getText()+"'where EID='"+textField.getText()+"'";
                    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, query);

                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);


                    pst.execute();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved successfully");

                    pst.close();


                }
                catch(Exception f)
                {
                    f.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setBounds(323, 349, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnUpdate);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try
                {

                    String query="delete from EmployeeInfo where EID='"+textField.getText()+"'";
                    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, query);

                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);


                    pst.execute();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data deleted successfully");

                    pst.close();


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnDelete.setBounds(453, 349, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: after this code what is happening? can you see all records from DB on `JTable`?

Comment: @Amogh:-  ..I am able to see all the records in my table without any error. Just want an unchecked checkbox to be added to each row so that when i click on it, i can do something. Thats my goal..

Comment: I have added answer..

Comment: @Amogh:- Thanks a lot. It looks complicated for a beginner like me but i will try. Also, if i want to create something like a cart where i can add stuffs from a table to my cart using only java, what approach should i follow? I am a bit confused. My ultimate goal is that i should be able to select a row from the table and add it to a cart and then pile up the cart. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes everything is possible in java and code world :). Just tell me one thing  all this you want to achieve in desktop application or web application?

Comment: @Amogh:- I want to make a desktop application. My ultimate aim would be to create an awesome course registration system but i am really really stuck with the part where a student can select a row from a table and add that course to his cart/schedule. Can you suggest me some in-depth tutorial that shows the a bit of these. I just need to understand a bit and from there on i can improvise and do some awesome stuffs.

Comment: Currently I don't have any tutorial for such (matching) stuff. but I have idea that once you are successful to show list of course with a checkbox then when any checkbox get selected you have to maintain a list course id will get store.

Comment: @Amogh:- Just needed some advise. Do you think that when a user clicks on the row and the items of the row are loaded into the textboxes and then there is this option called say "Add to Course Schedule" and when the user clicks on it the details are added to the course schedule. Is that a good idea? I just wanted an alternative to the whole checkbox thingy. Hope am not asking much!

Comment: Not at all you are asking just a bit :), but just be careful that you don't go Off topic otherwise anyone can put this post on `off-topic`. About "Add to Course Schedule", yes you would be the nice idea and ofcourse this could be easy then checkbox, because say for "Add to Course Schedule" we added a link label on `TableModel` so after clicking it in Click action we can add that (clicked) course to an list which holds the course id list. after on separate panel/form we can show added courses from that list

Comment: @Amogh:- Thank you so much...I got to learn a lot from you.. You are simply awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is you first go through [this article](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/), it's a very simpler way of loading data from `ResultSet` to `DefaultTableModel`. After this you have to make some small changes like, you have to add another column heading to the Vector of columnNames and add a column for check boxes. Then when you process each row from the ResultSet you need to add a Boolean value to the row Vector with a checkbox .